# Found text" " where item tag is expected

Tags: android

I added a colors.xml to my resources and wrote the following xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
   <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
   <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
   <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
   <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
   <color name="gray">#808080</color>
   <color name="olive">#808000</color>
   <color name="purple">#800080</color>
   <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
   <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
   <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
   <color name="teal">#008080</color>
   <color name="green">#008000</color>
   <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
   <color name="navy">#000080</color>
   <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

I use AIDE on my mobile to develop, it throws an error:

> Found text"  " where item tag is expected

please advise
thanks

Comment: The 4 spaces at the beginning are the only thing that jump out at me, though I wasn't sure if that was a copy/paste error here or if that's what might be the problem you're running into.

Comment: @Aldryd: I suggest you post that as an answer because it's right (the bit about the whitespace before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` I mean). Eclipse will also throw a build exception if there is any whitespace at the beginning of an XML document.

Comment: Thanks  Aldryd that was the correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the 4 whitespace characters at the beginning of the file are the problem that you're running into.

Comment: wierdly found this in the middle of the file as well, thank you, this did solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Having non-breakable space characters (&nbsp;/&#160;/&#xa0;) in your XML file where the ADK tools is expecting whitespace will cause this problem. Replace the non-breakable space characters with regular spaces. xmllint is useful for tracking down where the problem characters are.

Answer (score 0):

open the xml file with MadEdit or any other Hex File editors, look for "C2 A0" and replace all with normal space.

Or simply in the command line

$sed -i 's/\xc2\xa0/ /g' /the/path/to/the/xml/file

Answer (score -1):

In my code i used capital S to write the string. I convert to small s and it worked. Thanks