# error Error parsing XML mismatched tag in string.xml

Tags: java, xml

LLog For : suspended_menu.apk

Log Type : Recompiling

Log Recorded At : Tue 30-06-2015 23:45:53.14

Log Recorded By : Advanced ApkTool v4.1.0 By BDFreak

---

max res 19, skipping drawable-v21
max res 19, skipping layout-v21
max res 19, skipping values-v21

F:\Downloads\Compressed\apkmanager\3-Out\suspended_menu.apk\res\values\strings.xml:74: error: Found text "
    " where item tag is expected

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description">navigate home</string>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_up_description">navigate up</string>
    <string name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description">more options</string>
    <string name="abc_action_mode_done">done</string>
    <string name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">see all</string>
    <string name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application">choose an app</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_clear">clear query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_query">search query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_search">search</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_submit">submit query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_voice">voice search</string>
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">share with</string>
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application">share with %s</string>
    <string name="umappupdate">app updating</string>
    <string name="umbreak_network">please make sure you are connected to internet,update failed</string>
    <string name="umdialog_installapk">the lastest version has been downloaded, install now ?</string>
    <string name="umgprscondition">(warning: not wifi condition)</string>
    <string name="umignore">ingore this</string>
    <string name="umnewversion">latest version:</string>
    <string name="umnotnow">not now</string>
    <string name="umtargetsize">target size:</string>
    <string name="umtoast_isupdating">updating....</string>
    <string name="umupdatecheck">2.4.2.20140520</string>
    <string name="umupdatecontent">update content</string>
    <string name="umupdatenow">update now</string>
    <string name="umupdatesize">update size:</string>
    <string name="umupdatetitle">new version found</string>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description_format">%1$s, %2$s</string>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_home_subtitle_description_format">%1$s, %2$s, %3$s</string>
    <string name="abc_search_hint">search…</string>
    <string name="abc_toolbar_collapse_description">collapse</string>
    <string name="about_title">about</string>
    <string name="accesibility_service">""analog return key", "news tips", need to set up - auxiliary functions, the list of services to open the menu service suspension. (at the top or bottom)

if the service is "unexpectedly shut down", please check whether the background management software to clean up, and then the software whitelisted。"</string>
    <string name = "accesibility_service_close">services shut down unexpectedly check whether the background management software cleanup if yes please whitelist software。</string>
    <string name = "add">add</string>
   <string name="any_click_read_msg_introduction">when turned on, click any gesture will be able to read the message bar</string>
    <string name="any_click_read_msg_summary">when turned on, when there is a message, click the icon or click the sidebar suspension can quickly read the message to ignore the current click action settings</string>
    <string name="any_click_read_msg_title">click the read message</string>
    <string name="app_name">suspension menu</string>
    <string name="auto_hind_app_list">auto-hide the program list</string>
    <string name="auto_hind_app_list_introduction">if the current application is the "list" in the application, the suspension will be automatically hide menu</string>
    <string name="auto_start_title">boot</string>
    <string name="backup">backup</string>
    <string name="backup_autp_info">there are currently no backup files, automatic backup is restored?</string>
    <string name="backup_exist_info">backup file already exists, overwrite?</string>
    <string name="backup_fail">backup failure</string>
    <string name="backup_info">"backup file will be saved:
file/floatmenu/back"</string>
    <string name="backup_setting_title">backup and restore</string>
    <string name="backup_suc">backup successful</string>
    <string name="cancel">cancel</string>
    <string name="cata_base_setting_title">basic settings</string>
    <string name="cata_experimental_features">experimental features</string>
    <string name="cata_float_view_feature_setting">appearance settings</string>
    <string name="cata_gesture_setting">gesture settings</string>
    <string name="cata_other_title">other settings</string>
    <string name="cata_right_top_gesture_setting">top right corner gesture settings</string>
    <string name="cata_top_left_gesture_setting">upper left corner gesture settings</string>
    <string name="cata_view_feature_setting_title">appearance settings</string>
    <string name="caution">note:</string>
    <string name="choose_feedback_way">select feedback</string>
    <string name="clear_function">clear all</string>
    <string name="click_for_restore_float_view">click the icon to restore suspended</string>
    <string name="click_for_restore_light">click to close the screen long bright</string>
    <string name="click_for_restore_side">click recovery sidebar</string>
    <string name="click_to_del">tip: click to remove content</string>
    <string name="combine_list_introduction">when performing key combination function, the function list will be executed within one time</string>
    <string name="combine_list_summary">function key combination will be executed within one time</string>
    <string name="combine_list_title">key combinations</string>
    <string name="confirm">determine</string>
    <string name="countdown_close_flash">to protect the flash automatically turns off two minutes after</string>
    <string name="d_defalut_menu">[{name:set up,type:0,packagename:com.android.settings,classname:com.android.settings.settings,menuid:0},{name:return key,type:1,order:back_key_no_root,menuid:0},{name:homebond,type:1,order:home_key,menuid:0},{name:mute,type:1,order:mute_toggle,menuid:0},{name:lock screen,type:1,order:lock_screen,menuid:0},{name:show notification bar,type:1,order:toggle_notifaction,menuid:0},{name:hide icons,type:1,order:switch_floatview,menuid:0}]</string>
    <string name="d_float_click">[{name: default menu, type: 2, menuid: 2}]</string>
    <string name="d_float_down">[{name: home key, type: 1, order: home_key, menuid: 0}]</string>
    <string name="d_float_left">[{name: return key, type: 1, order: back_key_no_root, menuid: 0}]</string>
    <string name="d_float_right">[{name: task button, type: 1, order: recent_key, menuid: 0}]</string>
    <string name="d_float_up"> [{name: show | hide suspension icon, type: 1, order: switch_floatview, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_no_root_content"> current features require root permission, if it is determined the phone has root, root can install the management software to manage root privileges, whether to download and install? </string>
    <string name="d_no_root_down"> download </string>
    <string name="d_no_root_title"> unable to get root privileges </string>
    <string name="d_side_left_down_click"> [{name: home key, type: 1, order: home_key, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_side_left_down_down"> [{name: display the notification bar, type: 1, order: toggle_notifaction, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_side_left_down_right"> [{name: return to the previous program, type: 1, order: switch_app, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_side_left_up_click"> [{name: home key, type: 1, order: home_key, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_side_left_up_right"> [{name: return key, type: 1, order: back_key_no_root, menuid: 0}] </string>
    <string name="d_top_right_click"> [{name: running the program, type: 2, menuid: 1}] </string>
    <string name="defaultmenuname"> default menu </string>
    <string name="define_floatingactionbutton" />
    <string name="del"> delete </string>
    <string name="del_confirm"> delete ok? </string>
    <string name="del_suc"> deleted successfully </string>
    <string name="double_home_title"> double-click the home button to lock the screen </string>
    <string name="drawer_close"> draw close </string>
    <string name="drawer_open"> draw open </string>
    <string name="dynamic_position"> dynamic menu position </string>
    after <string name="dynamic_position_introduction"> open, pop-up menus dynamically adjusted based on the location of the sidebar position </string>
    <string name="dynamic_position_summary"> after opening, the position of the pop-up menu will be dynamically adjusted based on the position of the gesture bar </string>
    <string name="erro_menu_name_duplicate"> same menu name already exists </string>
    <string name="erro_menu_name_is_null"> enter the correct menu name </string>
    <string name="erro_menu_name_null"> menu name can not be empty </string>
    <string name="error_menu_has_been_del"> menu has been deleted </string>
    <string name="error_net"> failed to load, please check your network </string>
    <string name="error_no_root_access"> without root privileges </string>
    <string name="evaluate_setting_title"> evaluation </string>
    <string name="exclude_apps_summary"> when you run these programs, hide icons, and other gestures suspension bar </string>
    <string name="exit"> exit </string>
    <string name="expired"> software expires, go to the store to download the latest version. </string>
    <string name="extra_setting"> more settings </string>
    <string name="feedback_setting_title"> feedback recommendation </string>
    <string name="feedback_title"> suggestion feedback </string>
    <string name="float_extra_setting_summary"> position fix, move freely, automatically and transparently, edge absorption </string>
    <string name="float_tu"> "" click ": the pop-up menu
"press": move icon "</string>
    <string name = "float_view_auto_side_model"> edge absorption </string>
    <string name = "float_view_auto_trans_model"> auto transparent </string>
    <string name = "float_view_freedom_move_model"> freedom of movement </string>
    <string name = "float_view_lock_model"> position lock </string>
    <string name = "float_view_touch_feedback"> touch animation </string>
    <string name = "function_click"> click </string>
    <string name = "function_double_click"> double click </string>
    <string name = "function_down"> fell </string>
    <string name = "function_left"> left slide </string>
    <string name = "function_long_pressed"> long press </string>
    <string name = "function_right"> right slide </string>
    <string name = "function_up"> slide </string> on
    <string name = "gesture_setting_title"> gesture settings </string>
    <string name = "hind_into_statebar"> to hide the status bar </string>
    <string name = "home_show_float_title"> home key to display the suspended icon </string>
    <string name = "ignore"> ignore </string>
    <string name = "info_long_pressed_pop"> [press] icon menu inside, you can "select menu style" and "edit menu" </string>
    <string name = "input_menu_name"> enter the menu name </string>
    <string name = "input_new_menu_name"> please enter a new menu name </string>
    <string name = "internal_theme"> built </string>
    <string name = "introduction_native_theme"> "no custom skin found
the picture folder on the sd card / floatmenu / custom / file
skin formats: png, size not larger than 200x200 "</string>
    <string name = "is_out_up_dismiss_summary"> after opening, if the slide gesture triggers the menu, lift your finger outside the menu, the menu disappears </string>
    <string name = "is_out_up_dismiss_title">, raising his hand to close the menu </string>
    <string name = "is_undo"> are undelete? </string>
    <string name = "item_menu_help"> help </string>
    <string name = "item_menu_setting"> other settings </string>
    <string name = "keep_light_close"> screen long bright close </string>
    <string name = "keep_light_open"> screen long bright open </string>
    <string name = "keyboard_cover_summary"> special note: after opening smartbar cause some applications display is not normal, such as sms interface unrealistic send button, please use discretion. </string>
    <string name = "keyboard_cover_title"> input method covering </string>
    <string name = "landscape_auto_hind_title"> horizontal screen auto-hide </string>
    <string name = "left_and_right_to_del"> sliding around deleted </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_author"> oleksandr melnykov </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_authorwebsite"> https://github.com/makovkastar/floatingactionbutton </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_isopensource"> true </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_librarydescription"> android google+ like floating action button which reacts on the list view scrolling events. becomes visible when the list view is scrolled up and invisible when scrolled down. </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_libraryname"> floatingactionbutton </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_libraryversion"> 1.0.0 </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_librarywebsite"> https://github.com/makovkastar/floatingactionbutton </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_licenseid"> mit </string>
    <string name = "library_floatingactionbutton_repositorylink"> https://github.com/makovkastar/floatingactionbutton </string>
    <string name = "like_this_one"> like </string>
    after <string name = "lock_model_summary"> open, you can set a long press gesture </string>
    <string name = "lock_notification_title"> lock screen message prompts </string>
    <string name = "lock_screen"> a key lock screen </string>
    <string name = "long_pressed_disable_summary"> mobile suspension icon </string>
    <string name = "long_pressed_to_edit"> prompt: "press" menu list can be edited menu </string>
    <string name = "menu_edit"> edit menu </string>
    <string name = "menu_transparency"> transparency </string>
    <string name = "native_theme"> local </string>
    <string name = "need_high_api"> currently feature only supports android4.1 and above </string>
    <string name = "need_position_lock_switch_on"> the suspension icon positions locked or free to move the switch is turned to set </string>
    <string name = "need_service_on"> in order to ensure the normal operation of the software, you need to open the menu service suspension. </string>
    <string name = "no_backup"> no backup file </string>
    <string name = "no_email_app"> email is not installed </string>
    <string name = "no_flash_permission"> no camera (pictures / videos) permission, please give appropriate permissions system settings </string>
    <string name = "no_notification"> there is currently no message notification </string>
    <string name = "no_running_apps"> is not currently running program </string>
    <string name = "no_sdcard"> can not be loaded sd card, make sure the available </string>
    <string name = "no_warm"> has opened </string>
    <string name = "not_support_this_function"> the current system does not support this feature </string>
    <string name = "notification_all_switches_closed"> all current switch is turned off </string>
    <string name = "notification_bluetooth_close"> bluetooth turned off </string>
    <string name = "notification_bluetooth_open"> bluetooth open </string>
    <string name = "notification_can_not_launch_short_cut"> unable to start fast program </string>
    <string name = "notification_dismiss_title"> 10s ignore the message after the prompt </string>
    <string name = "notification_force_show_float"> mandatory message prompts </string>
    after <string name = "notification_force_show_float_introduction"> open, regardless suspension icon switch is turned on, will be forced to display a message prompts </string>
    <string name = "notification_gprs_close"> data flow shutdown </string>
    <string name = "notification_gprs_open"> data traffic open </string>
    after <string name = "notification_introduction"> open, notification bar when there is news, suspension icon will prompt no message read </string>
    <string name = "notification_mute_close"> mute off </string>
    <string name = "notification_mute_open"> mute on </string>
    <string name = "notification_not_install_mms"> you have not yet installed pop information, please download and install </string>
    <string name = "notification_not_install_profile"> you have not installed the magic with the change, please download and install </string>
    <string name = "notification_not_install_query_charges"> you have not yet installed a key inquiry calls, please download and install </string>
    <string name = "notification_not_install_quick_clean"> you have not installed or cheetah cleanup lbe masters, please download and install </string>
    <string name = "notification_rotation_close"> screen rotation close </string>
    <string name = "notification_rotation_open"> screen rotation open </string>
    <string name = "notification_summary"> icon suspension prompt qq, micro letters and other news, click read </string>
    <string name = "notification_title"> message prompts </string>
    <string name = "notification_vibreate_close"> vibrate off </string>
    <string name = "notification_vibreate_open"> vibration open </string>
    <string name = "notification_white_list_introduction"> only when the application "white list" have a notification message within, will have a message prompts </string>
    <string name = "notification_white_list_title"> message whitelist </string>
    <string name = "notification_wifi_close"> wi-fi turned off </string>
    <string name = "notification_wifi_open"> wi-fi to open </string>
    <string name = "nvg_float"> suspension icon </string>
    <string name = "nvg_menu"> menu settings </string>
    <string name = "nvg_notification"> message prompts </string>
    <string name = "nvg_other"> other settings </string>
    <string name = "nvg_side"> gestures side bar </string>
    <string name = "nvg_top"> gesture top bar </string>
    <string name = "official_version"> official version </string>
    <string name = "online_theme"> online </string>
    <string name = "open"> to open </string>
    <string name = "open_accessibility_service_title"> ○ settings -> accessibility -> "suspension menu" under the list of services </string>
    <string name = "open_notification_service_title"> ○ settings -> security -> notification read permission -> "suspension menu" </string>
    <string name = "open_service_title"> need to open the following services to run properly </string>
    <string name = "open_tip"> tip: if the service is frequently shut down, make sure the software is added to the white list system or other back office management software </string>.
    <string name = "opened"> turned </string>
    <string name = "over_write"> cover </string>
    <string name = "p_add_menu_title"> "add menu" </string>
    <string name = "p_notification_title"> "prompt message" </string>
    <string name = "p_online_theme_title"> "live skin" </string>
    <string name = "p_point_cost_content"> current total% 1 $ d points, unlock% 2 $ s% 3 $ d consumed points left after unlocking% 4 $ d integration, whether unlock? </string>
    <string name = "p_point_get_content"> current total% 1 $ d points, unlock% 2 $ s% 3 $ d consumed points, just under% 4 $ d integral unlock function, whether free access points? </string>
    <string name = "p_point_item_get_points"> get points </string>
    <string name = "p_point_item_unlock"> unlocked </string>
    <string name = "p_point_loading_content"> points get in ... </string>
    <string name = "p_title"> tip </string>
    <string name = "p_unlock_failed"> unlock failed </string>
    <string name = "p_unlock_suc"> unlock success </string>
    <string name = "pop_auto_kill_tip"> if you can not "show suspension icon," go to system settings open "floating window permissions" suspension of the menu. </string>
    <string name = "pop_auto_kill_tip_for_meizu"> "1. if the software" automatic shutdown ", set the software to join the white list cleaning software.

2. if the "unable to boot", make sure the software has permission to boot. "</string>
    <string name = "pop_auto_kill_tip_for_xiaomi"> "thanks to kabbu1 detected in your mobile phone miui system, you need the following settings to normal use:

miui v5 system:
settings - applications - suspension menu
open the "display floating window" rights.

miui v6 system:
security center - application management - suspension menu
open the "display floating window" rights. "</string>
    <string name = "pref_float_view_size_title"> size </string>
    <string name = "pref_float_view_theme"> skin </string>
    <string name = "pref_float_view_trans_title"> transparency </string>
    <string name = "purchase_official"> buy the official version </string>
    <string name = "questions"> frequently asked questions list </string>
    <string name = "rename"> rename </string>
    <string name = "restore"> recovery </string>
    <string name = "restore_suc"> successful recovery </string>
    <string name = "running_app"> running programs </string>
    <string name = "running_switch_app_black_list_summary"> list within the program will not be displayed or switched </string>
    <string name = "running_switch_app_black_list_title"> running programs / handover procedure blacklist </string>
    <string name = "save_comfirm_title"> enter to save? </string>
    <string name = "scr_menu_style_title"> menu style </string>
    <string name = "scr_other_setting_title"> other settings </string>
    <string name = "screen_shot_auto_hind"> screenshot hide </string>
    <string name = "screen_shot_auto_hind_summary"> via software screenshots, icons and sidebar hidden suspension </string>
    <string name = "screen_shot_show_summary"> only for the screenshot feature within the program </string>
    <string name = "screen_shot_show_title"> screenshot hide suspension icons </string>
    <string name = "screen_shot_tip"> "will have vibration feedback after successful shots, pictures will be saved to:
sdcard / pictures / screenshots / "</string>
    <string name = "service_describe"> case of non-root "analog return key", "the message tips", need to open this service </string>
    <string name = "service_destroy"> suspension menu service shut down unexpectedly, check that background management software has been added to the whitelist </string>
    <string name = "show_notification_msg_summary"> after opening, if [the message] whitelist program has a message notification, suspension icon automatically becoming an icon for the program to prompt a new message arrives, click to read the message </string>
    <string name = "show_notification_msg_switch_title"> message prompts </string>
    after <string name = "show_side_introduction"> turned back to the desktop will continue to display the sidebar </string>
    after <string name = "show_side_summary"> open, exit the program continues to display the location of the next portion of the sidebar </string>
    <string name = "show_side_title"> sidebar </string>
    <string name = "side_distinguish_up_down_title"> distinguish between upper and lower portions </string>
    <string name = "side_gesutre_setting_title"> sidebar gesture settings </string>
    <string name = "side_left_down_setting"> "at the left part of" gesture </string>
    <string name = "side_left_up_setting"> "on the left part of the" gesture </string>
    <string name = "side_left_view_switch_title"> left side of the gesture column switch </string>
    <string name = "side_left_width"> left side width </string>
    <string name = "side_length"> length </string>
    <string name = "side_position"> location </string>
    <string name = "side_right_down_setting"> "under the right part of the" gesture </string>
    <string name = "side_right_up_setting"> "on the right-hand part of the" gesture </string>
    <string name = "side_right_view_switch_title"> on the right gesture column switch </string>
    <string name = "side_right_width"> on the right width </string>
    <string name = "slide_del_running_app"> slide remove the running program </string>
    <string name = "slide_del_running_app_attention"> "note:
after opening, the surface may appear not click on the pop-up menu on some phones, please caution. "</string>
    after <string name = "slide_del_running_app_introduction"> open, when the pop-up menu to "running program - a vertical", you can slide around the end of the program, you need root privileges. </string>
    <string name = "start"> began to experience </string>
    <string name = "style"> style </string>
    <string name = "switch_anim"> start / switch procedural animation </string>
    applications within the <string name = "switch_black_list_introduction"> "list" does not appear in the running list and will not be switched </string>
    <string name = "switch_float_view_title"> suspension icon switch </string>
    <string name = "switch_off_freedom_model_first"> turn off the free movement of switch </string>
    <string name = "switch_off_lock_model_first"> turn off location lock switch </string>
    <string name = "switch_on_service"> open </string>
    <string name = "t_notification_float_msg"> when the notification bar when the news: \ u0009 </string>
    <string name = "t_notification_float_normal"> suspension icon looks like a normal time: \ u0009 </string>
    <string name = "t_start_float_like_this"> long suspension icon like this: \ u0009 </string>
    <string name = "test"><font color ="red">update settings</font></string>
    <string name="test_modle">beta</string>
    <string name="test_version">trial</string>
    <string name = "toggle_screen_func_introduction">1. trigger pull-down screen automatically restored after hovering five seconds.

2. dropdown hovering situation may arise gesture bar / suspension position of the icon can not be restored, wait 5 seconds automatic recovery</string>
    <string name = "top_gesutre_setting_title"> top gesture settings </string>
    <string name = "top_left_view_switch_title"> upper left corner of the switch </string>
    <string name = "top_right_view_switch_title"> the top right corner switch </string>
    <string name = "top_view_left_width_title"> top left corner width </string>
    <string name = "top_view_right_width_title"> the top right corner width </string>
    <string name = "tutorial_float_content"> "" click ": the pop-up menu
"press": move icon
"slide": hide icons
"decline": analog home button
"left slide": switch on a program
"right slide": switch to the next program "</string>
    <string name = "tutorial_float_title"> "suspension icon" default settings </string>

</resources>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where is the code?

Comment: why some are capitalized, some not? where are the starting tag and the final tag?

Comment: It says error in this line: <String name ="any_click_read_msg_introduction">When turned on click any gesture column can read the message</string>

Answer (score 0):

The start tag is Capitalized `<String>` while the end tag is not `</string>`

```
<String name ="any_click_read_msg_introduction">When turned on click any gesture column can read the message</string>
```

EDIT:
The original question was edited (it appears the above answer was a correct one)
Regarding the new problem: it is not reprodcible with the edited xml. according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299646/android-applicationerror-found-text) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754677/found-text-where-item-tag-is-expected) it is possible you have some extra blank (or unprintable) characters somewhere in the file that didn't pass the copy-paste to SO.

However, the file still has some issues with its structure:

1. There is extra text outside of the `<string>` tags (for example, at line #100 search for `dynamic_position_introduction`) this occurs in several lines.
2. an attribute assignment should not have spaces. there are multiple `<string name = "` that should be replaced with `<string name="`

Comment: Corrected it still same error "Found tag String where item is expected"

Comment: First of all, the error message is different so this is obviously **not** the same error.  second, what did you correct?, third, when I lowercased **ALL** <String> and </String> tags, the file is parsed successfully

Comment: All "strings" letters were lower-cased and still issue persist.I had edited my question now.

Comment: so your original problem did get an answer. it is not customary to replace original question with new one, since it makes the answers irrelevant (bare in mind others might stumble upon this thread with their problems). anyway I edited my orig answer with the best effort I made to give an answer to the new problem. this is a simple matter of XML validation and there is plenty of info on this matter at your nearest search engine.